# selecting max value in the column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data like this

```
TagID,ListnerID,Timestamp,Sum_RSSI
2,101,1496745906,90
3,102,1496745907,70
3,104,1496745906,80
2,101,1496745909,60
4,106,1496745908,60
```

My expected output would be

```
2,101,1496745906,90
3,104,1496745906,80
4,106,1496745908,60
```

I tried like this

```
val high_window = Window.partitionBy($"tagShortID")
val prox = averageDF
.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window.orderBy($"Sum_RSSI".desc)))
.filter($"rank" === 1)
```

But it prints all the rows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your window is defined as `high_window` and you're using `window.orderBy`

Comment: Hay thanks for pointing out. It works now!